# Lines not showing up on canvas when setting symbology in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins

in my code I'm doing this:

```
    self.final_lines = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), "final_lines", "postgres")
    mySymbol1 = QgsFillSymbol.createSimple({
        'color':'120,190,33,255',
        'outline_width': '0.66'})
    self.final_lines.renderer().setSymbol(mySymbol1)
    print(self.final_lines.renderer().symbol().symbolLayers()[0].properties())
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(self.final_lines)
```

and the print out for the properties() is:

```
{'border_width_map_unit_scale': '3x:0,0,0,0,0,0', 'color': '120,190,33,255', 'joinstyle': 'bevel', 'offset': '0,0', 'offset_map_unit_scale': '3x:0,0,0,0,0,0', 'offset_unit': 'MM', 'outline_color': '35,35,35,255', 'outline_style': 'solid', 'outline_width': '0.66', 'outline_width_unit': 'MM', 'style': 'solid'}
```

But no lines show up on the canvas, if I don't set this in qgis and let it set its own then they show up, but I want to specify lime green with a width of 0.66 for this line layer.

Comment: You are trying to use a `QgsFillSymbol` (which is meant for rendering Polygon geometries https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsFillSymbol.html) on a line layer. If you simply replace `QgsFillSymbol` with `QgsLineSymbol` in your code, your problem will be solved!

Comment: @BenW Oh wow, thank you!

Comment: No worries! You're welcome :-)

Comment: @BenW, please put your comment as a valid answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to set a [QgsFillSymbol](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsFillSymbol.html) (which is designed for rendering polygon geometries) to a line layer.

You need to use a [QgsLineSymbol](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsLineSymbol.html) instead.

E.g.

```py
mySymbol1 = QgsLineSymbol.createSimple({
    'color':'120,190,33,255',
    'outline_width': '0.66'})
```